# Remove path from find command output

Tags: bash, find

I have a bash script for deploying code from a beta environment to a production environment but currently I have to add the list of files to a txt file manaully and sometime I miss some. Basically my deployment script cat/loops copying the files over. (exports/imports db as well but that's not relevant..lol)

Anyway, I'd like to use the `find` command to generate a list of files modified in the last 14 days. The problem is I need to strip the path out `./` in order for the deployment script to work.

Here's an  example of the find command usage:

> find . -type f -mtime -14 > deploy.txt

Here's the line that cats `deploy.txt` in my deployment script:

```
for i in `cat deploy.txt`; do cp -i /home/user/beta/public_html/$i /home/user/public_html/$i; done
```

Any idea how to accomplish this using bash scripting?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use rsync for this? It sounds as if you may be trying to reinvent the wheel and make it a triangle.

Comment: valid point however before deployment the deploy.txt is reviewed and anything that needs fixing gets removed

Comment: Maybe run rsync in `--dry-run` mode and output that to a file for review?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use the `-printf` command line option with `%f` to print just the filename without any directory information

```
find . -type f -mtime -14 -printf '%f\n' > deploy.txt
```

or you can use sed to just remove the ./

```
find . -type f -mtime -14 | sed 's|^./||' >deploy.txt
```

Comment: I believe you have to escape the `/.`.

Comment: Not when you use `|` as the delimiter.

Comment: Using `%f` will strip off all directories, not just `./`. This will break his deployment script if any of the files returned by `find` are located in subdirectories.

Comment: No kidding. That's good to know. :)

Comment: @JamesSneeringer: I know but it's not entirely clear what the OP wants and I did mention that in my answer too

Comment: @Iain You do need to escape the `.` though. And maybe best to use a start-of-line anchor: `s|^\./||`

Comment: @Iain: So you did, my bad. :)

Comment: Use `%P` instead of `%f`. This just cut off the path given in the command line.

Comment: This seems like a nice, but Linux-only trick. Regular `find(1)` -- such as that found on FreeBSD, for example, does not have the `-printf` predicate...

Answer (score 15):

The `./` should be harmless. Most programs will treat `/foo/bar` and `/foo/./bar` as equivalent. I realize it doesn't look very nice, but based on what you've posted, I see no reason why it would cause your script to fail.

If you really want to strip it off, `sed` is probably the cleanest way:

```
find . -type d -mtime 14 | sed -e 's,^\./,,' > deploy.txt
```

If you're on a system with GNU find (e.g. most Linux systems), you can do it in one shot with `find -printf`:

```
find . -type d -mtime 14 -printf "%P\n" > deploy.txt
```

The `%P` returns the complete path of each file found, minus the path specified on the command line, up to and including the first slash. This will preserve any subdirectories in your directory structure.

Comment: The `./` prefix is actually a feature; without it, piping output to other commands will not work correctly e.g. for file names which start with a dash.

Comment: @tripleee - I understand the utility of it, but OP specifically asked how to strip it off because it was causing problems for his deployment script. Sure, there might be better ways to do what he needs to do, but that's a rabbit hole well beyond the scope of what was asked.

Comment: `rsync` for example won't in some situations when you use `find` to cretae pattern files.

Answer (score 7):

Why do you need to strip off the `./`? It is valid to have it in the middle of a path. So

```
cp -i dir1/./somefile dir2/./somefile
```

is just OK!

But if you would like to strip off the directory name using `find`, you can use the `%P` arg to `-printf`.

man [find(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) says:

> ```
>          %P     File's name with the name of the  command  line  argument
> ```

```
                 under which it was found removed.
```

An example

```
$ find other -maxdepth 1
other
other/CVS
other/bin
other/lib
other/doc
other/gdbinit
$ find other -maxdepth 1 -printf "%P\n"

CVS
bin
lib
doc
gdbinit
```

Mind the first empty line! If you want to avoid it use `-mindepth 1`

```
$ find other -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf "%P\n"
CVS
bin
lib
doc
gdbinit
```

Comment: Yes, it is valid when specifying paths to be interpreted by the system but it will change behavior when using the find output to generate file list for other tools, e.g. `rsync` include/exclude lists.

Answer (score 7):

"find -printf" solution won't work on FreeBSD because find don't have such an option.
In this case AWK can help. It returns a last name ($NF), so it can work on any depth.

```
find /usr/local/etc/rc.d -type f | awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

PS: taken from D.Tansley "Linux and Unix shell programming" book

Answer (score 4):

Well you have a few options.  You could use the `-printf` option in find to only print out the filename, or you could use a tool like sed to simply strip out the `./`.

```
# simply print out the filename, will break if you have sub-directories.
find . -mtime -14 -printf '%f\n'

# strip a leading ./
find .  -mtime -14 | sed -e 's/^\.\///'
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of it's usage? Sorry, linux is not really my forté

Comment: Look again, there are examples.

Comment: Agreed - just try it, you're not going to hurt anything running a combination of find and sed.

Answer (score 3):

A quick solution, if I understand correctly the question, is using `cut` on the output of the `find` command:

```
$> find . -type f -mtime -14 | cut -b 3- > deploy.txt
```

This will strip the first to characters from each line of the result (in your case `./`). Probably not the best solution, but works in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is perfect for this sort of thing.

```
$ find . -type f -mtime -14 find . | sed 's/^\.\///' > deploy.txt
```

Comment: Small tip: `sed` allows you to use any other character instead of `/` as separator. When working with paths, this is pretty useful as it requires less escaping: `sed 's|^\./||'`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kind of filenames we're talking about, but anything with spaces or newlines puts most of the solutions here at risk.

My suggestion would be to use shell's parameter expansion to strip of the characters from each filename:

```
find . -mtime -14 -exec sh -c 'printf "${0#./}\n"' {} \; >deploy.txt
```

If you really really like pipes, you could use a "safe" delimiter, like a null, with xargs to receive each filename:

```
find . -mtime -14 -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 sh -c 'printf "${0#./}\n"' >deploy.txt
```

Remember that the output of this is *NOT* null-delimited, so while it may be sufficient for an eyeball check, none of these solutions produce a deploy.txt file that is safe to use for automation, unless you're very confident about your source filenames.